# Não consigo alinhar a logo

Tags: html, css

Gostaria de alinhar o `<h1>` e `<p>` no cento da página, sou novo na programação web e ainda não sei muita coisa. Se alguém puder ajudar agradeço :)

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: 0px;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #01003d;
}

button {
  font-family: 'Sora', sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

a {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -30px;
}

.header-content {
  margin-top: 0px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

i {
  color: white;
  font-size: 150%;
}

.header-icons {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}

#i:hover {
  color: #ff00bb;
}

#w:hover {
  color: #00d134;
}

.header-logo {
  display: relative;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 200px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .header-content {
    margin-top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  header {
    margin-top: 0px;
  }
  .header-logo img {
    width: 150px;
  }
  .org {
    min-height: 60vh;
  }
  h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 34px;
    padding: 0 14px;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .header-logo img {
    width: 120px;
  }
  .org {
    min-height: 50vh;
  }
  h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 28px;
    padding: 0 14px;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.container {
  max-width: 1440px;
  margin: 0 8px;
}

.bg-home {
  position: relative;
}

.bg-home::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(6, 18, 30, 0.1), #01003d), url("img/FundoLanding.jpg");
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 0;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.org {
  color: white;
  min-height: 80vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 150%;
  max-width: 940px;
  font-size: 46px;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 14px 0;
}

.button-acess {
  padding: 14px 28px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #001a80;
  border: 2px solid;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-color: white;
}

.button-acess:hover {
  background-color: #000657;
}

.button-teste {
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
  background-color: #001a80;
  padding: 12px 22px;
}

.button-teste:hover {
  background-color: #000657;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Landing Page de One Piece</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="bg-home">
    <header>
      <nav class="header-content container">
        <div class="header-icons">
          <a href="#">
            <i class="bi bi-instagram" id="i"></i>
          </a>
          <a href="#">
            <i class="bi bi-whatsapp" id="w"></i>
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class="header-logo">
          <img src="img/Luffy2 (2).svg" alt="Logo da Landing Page">
        </div>

        <div>
          <a href="https://pt.quizur.com/quiz/qual-dos-mugiwaras-vc-seria-LA9M" class="button-teste">Qual Mugiwara você seria?</a>
        </div>
      </nav>

      <main class="org container">
        <h1>One Piece</h1>
        <p><a href="#" class="button-acess" target="_blank">Acessar o site principal</a></p>
      </main>
    </header>
  </div>




</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Cara, para isso você precisa arrumar o seu CSS para centralizar as duas tags que deseja, pode adicionar essas propriedades no .org

```css
        .org {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  min-height: 80vh;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px;
}
```

caso dê algo errado precisará rever os estilos do h1 e p no seu css

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).